# Incorrect syntax near '=' when passing uniqueidentifier as parameter in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
alter PROCEDURE TEST(
@table nvarchar(50),
@id uniqueidentifier
)
AS
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'select * from ' + @table + 'where ID = ' + CAST(@id as nvarchar(36));
exec (@sql)
```

how I test it:

```
EXEC TEST 'testable','F6BFBA52-B898-4246-9F58-001DFBDA32ED'
```

And I keep getting error:Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: You are missing a space before `where`, so table name is "glued" to the keyword: `'where ID = `...

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL HERE...your procedure is extremely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @dasblinkenligh, I added space, now it's telling me Incorrect syntax near 'F58'.

Comment: The best way to debug dynamic sql is not by executing it. You should select or print @sql to examine the contents of your dynamic sql first.

Comment: If you use `nvarchar`, you should *always* use the `N'....'` notation with a leading `N` prefix to indicate Unicode string literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use system stored procedure `sp_executesql` when working with dynamic sql.

use `SYSNAME` data type for sql server objects (tables, columns) parameters.

When expecting objects names from end user, you will end up concatenating them, Use `QUOTENAME()` function around them parameters which enforces square brackets `[]` around these concatenated params and forces sql server to treat them params as sql server object names, Protection against sql injection attack.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
(
    @table SYSNAME,
    @id uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    set @sql = N'select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + N' where [ID] = @id';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
                         ,N'@id uniqueidentifier'
                         ,@id
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you understand the dangers of generating SQL like this dynamically, you are missing a space and single quotes in the SQL that you generate:

```
set @sql = N'select * from ' + @table + N' where ID = N''' + CAST(@id as nvarchar(36)) + N'''';
--                                        ^             ^^                                 ^^
```

Comment: If you use `nvarchar`, you should *always* use the `N'....'` notation with a leading `N` prefix to indicate Unicode string literals

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this-

```
alter PROCEDURE TEST(
   @table nvarchar(50),
   @id uniqueidentifier
)
AS
   declare @sql nvarchar(max)

   set @sql = N'select * from ' + @table + 'where ID = ' + char(39) + CAST(@id as nvarchar(38)) + char(39);
   exec (@sql)
```

Comment: If you use `nvarchar`, you should *always* use the `N'....'` notation with a leading `N` prefix to indicate Unicode string literals